# Check is option selected in drop down list?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem, rspec-expectations

I try to check is selected option realy selected in drop down list (select):

```
expect(page.sltMembers_element.options).to eql('John Doe')
```

But I get an error that expected: 'John Doe'
and got: list of all options from drop down list.

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498575/get-select-value-of-dropdown-for-capybara-testing. Looks like 

    find_field('restrictions__rating_movies').find('option[selected]').text

should do

Comment: @CoupDeMistral, `find_field` and `find` are Capybara gem methods. This question is about using the Page-Object gem with Watir-Webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `sltMembers_element` method is the one generated by the `select_list` accessor, then the page-object will have 5 methods:

1. `sltMembers` returns the currently selected item text.
2. `sltMembers=` selects an item.
3. `sltMembers_element` returns the page-object element.
4. `sltMembers?` checks if the element is present.
5. `sltMembers_options` gets an array of all available options.

As you want to check the selected option, you want to call the page's `sltMembers` method:

```
expect(page.sltMembers).to eql('John Doe')
```