# Using assert_select to find a select box value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm struggling to test whether my select box has a value of 6.

```
<form class="edit_line_item" id="edit_line_item_7" action="/line_items/7" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
    <select name="line_item[quantity]" id="line_item_quantity"><option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

My rspec code

```
assert_select "select#line_item_quantity", value: 6
```

Whatever I change the value to my test still passes so I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To use `assert_select` this way you have to pass it a block and do your assertion on the array of elements passed to the block.

`assert_select` is "An assertion that selects elements and makes one or more equality tests"

Example:

```
 assert_select "ol" do |elements|
   elements.each do |element|
     assert_select element, "li", 4
   end
 end
```

You need to tweak this example to assert based on the `value` attribute of the option tag within the selected element (a `select` tag in this case).

I recommend reading the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select

If you're using capybara you can use `have_select`. Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622979/156746